# Jekyll Ignoring markdown headings

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I have the following markdown file for a jekyll site:

https://github.com/eQualityTime/TheOpenVoiceFactory/blob/gh-pages/guides.md,  which parses correctly in github.

However, something goes wrong when I parse with jekyll process and the headers look like this after I build them (full site is [this one](http://www.theopenvoicefactory.org/guides.html)):

[image]

What's causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **_includes/singlepage.html**, you call `{{ page.content }}`, which is the unprocessed content. Replace it by `{{ content }}`.